# Hcitool scan detect mobile but Bluez Inquiri not

Tags: bluetooth, rssi

I'm trying get the RSSI of Android and Apple Mobiles.

I can detect them with hcitool scan but when I run my program with  [blueZ inquisitor](http://www.wensley.org.uk/c/inq/inq.c) I can't detect the must recent mobiles. With my old nokia and apple mouse, the program can detect but with others no...

I'm using BlueZ 3.36... What should I do to detect RSSI value of the newest mobiles?

Comment: I have used this example successfully.  Does it work for you? http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py?r=1

Comment: Which version of Bluez did you used?

Comment: I solve this problem (I saw this thread today). The source code is available at: https://github.com/dnascimento/RasperryBluetoothLocalizer